# Google webfont loader crashing ie - hard

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-font-api

I'm trying to use a jquery-plugin called bigText. An awesome plugin for create block-headers. If you want to use this with a custom font, it states that you need google webfont loader, this way you can use a callback to trigger the plugin AFTER the @fontface has loaded/rendered.

It works fine in FF, Safari, Chrome, but it keeps crashing ie6-7-8, hard. A soon as the page loads it says it has an error and asks if you want to send a report to MS.

[You can check out the code here](http://labs.stijnd.be/photo_tool/)

I'm sure this is triggered by the Google font loader, When commenting out all the other parts of the code it still seems to crash. When commenting out the google font-loader bit, all the other things work => [font loader only example](http://labs.stijnd.be/photo_tool/ie_test.php)

Has anyone here ever experienced a bug like this and maybe found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I have had the same bug.

The first note is that you must reproduce the bug on NATIVE IE 6-8, not IE 9 using the Dev Tools -> Browser Mode.

I have **isolated the bug to an incompatibility with Modernizr 2.5.2**, simply upgrade your modernizr build and you'll be all set~

EDIT - Just upgrade to the latest version 2.5.3 of [Your Build Here](http://www.modernizr.com/download/#-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-mq-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load)

**Edit 2 — Verified that it's fixed on our [Orlando Web Design Page](http://mycircletree.com/)**